# JavaScript Input field not editable?

Tags: javascript, html

Fellow i have the following code

```
<script language="javascript">

   my_row_html = "<input type='text' value='"+node.data.pkey+"' width='300px'>";
</Script>
```

when the output comes the field is not editable can anybody help me to fix it thanks

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do??? It's so wrong in so many ways!

Comment: Try this: `my_row_html = '<input type="text" value="'+node.data.pkey+'" width="300" />';`

Comment: how you insert this variable? Paste your full js code please.

Comment: @kevin628. This is still wrong, not just because he doesn't seem to use that variable, you can't have `width` attribute

Comment: i am trying to return html text field from javascript, you can ignore  "my_row_html =" this.

Comment: @gdoron That shouldn't matter.  I'm just trying to help him get an editable field to show up.  I didn't say it was perfectly right, hence why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @ShamAli. You won't get a helpful answer without explain what you're trying to do **and how**.

Comment: @Sham Ali ok, but is totally wrong this code...

Comment: @kevin628. You're wasting your time on "not a real question"...

Comment: yes i am inserting variable on it '+node.data.pkey+' the value display in the output but i cant edit it. most interesting thing is that if i press single click on the field i can edit it else not, and i can not delete the data that i have inserted with pressing single click

Comment: @gdoron Apologies, gdoron.  I prefer to help people before I report their question, if I can.  I see this attitude is a mistake on SO.  I will not fail again in the future.

Comment: @kevin628. From my experience, this is not helping them. He needs to take a course in javascript-html. Not asking questions about editable input. I appreciate your good will, but [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using **jQuery**:

```
$('<input />').appendTo('#container');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any page element, including inputs dynamically via JavaScript. You can do it via a JavaScript framework, like jQuery, or directly through the dom. You can see quite a number of examples for doing this by checking the list of Google query results below:

[Google answers the question better than i do](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=javacript%20createelement&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=opera&hs=UoB&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=javascript%20dynamically%20create%20input&oq=javascript%20dynamically%20create%20input&aq=f&aqi=g-K4&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0i30l4.35455.41077.0.43274.35.16.0.18.18.3.222.2686.0j14j2.16.0...0.0.t7qr1rqHCM0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=e1bee19225e94f5e&biw=1164&bih=892)